# Set color to text while rendering HTML view in UITextView swift

Tags: ios, swift, nsattributedstring

I am rendering a HTML view in an UITextView using swift. Here is the code.

```
guard let attributedString = try? NSAttributedString(data: htmlContent.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)!, options: [NSAttributedString.DocumentReadingOptionKey.documentType : NSAttributedString.DocumentType.html], documentAttributes: nil)  else {
            return
        }



textView.attributedText = attributedString
```

Now I want to set color of the text to white. How to do it?

Comment: Init the `attributedString ` as a `NSMutableAttributedString`, not a `NSAttributedString` and do `attributedString.addAttribute(NSAttributedStringKey.foreground, value: UIColor.white range:NSRange(location: 0, length: attributedString.length)` (or something like that), or edit the `htmlContent` string to add a color with a HTML tag (simpler?).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply use the textView's `textColor` property:

```
// ...
textView.attributedText = attributedString
textView.textColor = .white
```

You could also set the `foregroundColor` on the attributed string itself - therefor you have to switch to an `NSMutableAttributedString` though:

```
// ...
attributedString.addAttribute(.foregroundColor, value: UIColor.white, range: NSRange(location: 0, length: attributedString.length))
textView.attributedText = attributedString
```